# How to install git for pip - python 2.7?

Tags: python, pip

My pip version is 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

I can't install git. what am I missing here?

```
$pip install git
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for git
```

Comment: Can you show what exactly happens when you run "pip install gitpython"?

Answer (score 1):

I  need to install

```
pip install gitpython
```